# MATLAB matrix - read file contains alphabet in column header and row header

Tags: regex, matlab, matrix

I have the following file structure

[image: matrix]

I would like to read the file and store them into a matrix form, I tried 
`dlmread('matrix' , ' ' , 1 , 1)` and it would not worked because of the "negative value" that prevent my delimiter from working properly as it is limit to "1 white space only".

I also tried `textscan()` but would like to know if there is any better method to workaround.

As my task is to extract the value from it. e.g. (2 , 2) will gives 5.

Due to the column and row header, I have no idea how to store them in a matrix form.

Any regex function that will work would be greater help as well.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you try the tab delimiter `\t`?

Comment: Checkout my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227309/how-to-import-complicated-csv-file-into-numerical-vectors-into-matlab/19242675#19242675 - I believe the same tool can help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the tips for the [`dlmread` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) they mention that if you want to use multiple white spaces as the delimiter and specify row/column offsets, you should use an empty string, i.e. `''` as the delimiter. This should solve your problem.

```
data = dlmread('matrix', '', 1, 1);
```